# Most hands-off AJAX builder / graphical dev environment

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a quick way to build the front-end AJAX for an administrative interface.

Is their a "Javascript Generator" similar for example to the Microsoft Visual dev environments where you can just place controls by hand in a graphical environment, and then double click the controls to enter the code that should power the object?

Here are the suggestions so far:

- RadPHP / PHP for Delphi
- WaveMaker
- SLinb
- Sigma Visual Widgets
- Sencha Ext Designer

Has anyone had good / bad experiences with any of thse?

Comment: I would guess that this doesn't exist - there are few such tools for web development. You could however try a javascript library such Jquery UI and YUI, both of which provide ready made controls which you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

[VisualJS](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_visual/VisualJS/) (online)

or maybe something like [Wavemaker](http://wavemaker.com/).

Is this what you were looking for?

I do warn you that (that I know of) you cant build AJAX applications as simple as you describe it.

Comment: Wavemaker looks awesome... would be better if it was only a front-end solution, or used a php back-end though... Still I might use it.

Answer (score 1):

[Sencha/EXT Designer](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/) may be what you're looking for. It's not free.